# Returning boolean from mongoose .exists function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to learn some node.js and mongoDB. I'm writing a demo login system to that end.

I have a function called by my main api to check in the mongoDB whether a refreshToken exists.

```
const checkRefreshTokenDB = (tokenPayload) => {
  const decoded = jwt.decode(tokenPayload);
  RefreshToken.exists(
    { tokenId: decoded.refresh.tokenId },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Result: ' + result);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

I can see the RefreshToken.exists is working find in the console.log. What I'm struggling with is making this function return a simple true/false to the caller. At the moment it seems to be returning a promise.

Any help would be very appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that checkRefreshTokenDB is returning a promise? It does not have a return statement anywhere.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure tbh, but I console.log(checkRefreshTokenDB(token) in my api route handler and I get back [object Promise] which as you say given checkRefreshTokenDB() doesn't have a return confuses me to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to resolve the issue is by using `async/await`.

```js
const checkRefreshTokenDB = async (tokenPayload) => {
  const decoded = jwt.decode(tokenPayload);
  return await RefreshToken.exists({ tokenId: decoded.refresh.tokenId });
};
```

Now you can call this function as shown below from an `async` function (`await` is only valid in async function)

```js
const status = await checkRefreshTokenDB(tokenPayload);
console.log(status)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it really is returning a promise, then use async/await:

```js
const checkRefreshTokenDB = (tokenPayload) => {
  const decoded = jwt.decode(tokenPayload);
  RefreshToken.exists(
    { tokenId: decoded.refresh.tokenId }
  , async function (err, result) { console.log(await result); });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I can get the correct true/false response from the function itself - my problem is getting that response back to the caller. When I console.log the response from this function I get [object Promise]

Comment: What about awaiting it inside the callback you did earlier? Modifying answer

Comment: I'm console.log-ing the function like so ```console.log(
        'refreshDBCheck = ' +
          refreshToken.checkRefreshTokenDB(req.cookies.refreshToken)
      ); ``` and getting refreshDBCheck = undefined

Comment: Do you still get the promise?